# DC Switching Boost Regulator at light load - power saving

Tags: pic, dc-dc-converter, boost, battery-operated

I am new to DC-DC switching boost regulator. In my application, I need regulated 3.3V output from 2 (1.5V) single alkaline batteries. I have a light load taking only about 0.5 mA most of the time and as per the user activity intermittently, power to a module is switched (with a load switch), which takes about 75 mA for about 250 mS.

In my experimental setup, I've used [TPS61201](http://www.ti.com/product/TPS61201/datasheet/detailed_description#SLVS5775052) / TPS63001 from Texas Instruments, which has a power save pin to reduce power consumption at light load.

My goal here is to increase the battery life as much as possible and be able to use the regulator down to about 1.6V from 3V of the alkaline batteries.

What I am trying to understand are as follow:

1. Can I keep the power save mode enabled all time time in my application with such DC regulators to minimize inductor current and to increase battery life?
2. What difference it would have in performance with power save mode enabled or disabled all the time?
3. With power save mode enabled, would the regulator start up with voltage as low as 1.6V or lower?

At the moment, I am evaluating different DC boost regulator and their characteristic curves for best efficiency in my application but your input would help me clarify my understanding about power save mode of such DC regulators and how to increase battery life for light loads for most of the usage duration.

Comment: If your goal is "to increase the battery life as much as possible," then there is a lot more to your question than you've written about. I assume you are using a micro. Which one? (This [and input and output transducers] is probably the largest single factor to consider.) Also, how is the device activated (powered-up?) The methodology here matters a lot regarding quiescent power when inactive. Also, all boost devices have a minimum load for operation. Answers to the above questions will have an impact on choice of boost topology, as well.

Comment: PIC micro. The DC boost converter remains disconnected from the battery when not in used with a pass transistor. PIC transfers some data with another modules and then goes to sleep. The other modules also go to sleep. When in sleep, I see that about 0.5mA is drawn from the input power supply (or batteries). When everything awake for about 250 mS during data transfer, ~75 mA is consumed. Do I need to have a dummy load in this case for minimum load requirements? That would be the waste of battery power with a dummy load..

Comment: this 0.5 mA with power save mode enabled. If I disable Power save mode of the DC regulator, the current consumption increases significantly..that tells me that DC regulator of my choice at the moment is not very efficient at light loads and DC regulator itself is taking a lot of current with power save mode disabled..

Comment: By no means am I suggesting you change your entire toolchain, but the PICs (and I *love* Microchip as a business partner, as anyone will tell you) -- even the nanowatt variety -- don't come anywhere even close to an MSP430 for long battery life. Once you look at the time it takes to "get up to speed" on a PIC, the MSP430 has already been there and done that and gone back to sleep, already. However, you have 75mA*250mS*Vcc or somewhere around 50 mJ per event. How long do you sleep between events?

Comment: To answer your direct question, yes according to the literature those particular regulators will run more efficiently if you run them in PS mode. The efficiency gained is dependent on how small the load current is. It's all in those hundreds of graphs they give you. However, as @jonk is highlighting, there is no point squeezing the last percentile of efficiency out of the regulator if your main charge loss is elsewhere. You need to optimize both.

Comment: it would be a variable but would be around 10 sec sleep between events for a power on duration of about 45 seconds; then 30 seconds of battery disconnect from DC regulator; then event followed by 10 sec sleep..

Comment: @Trevor, it looks like DC regulator itself takes a lot of juice - I say that b'coz if I use in PS enabled mode, the system draws only about 0.5mA when micro and all other sleep. But in PS mode disabled, the current consumption increases a lot..My main concern is can I just keep PS mode enabled all the time? Would it work down to about 1.4V in PS mode enabled?

Comment: Hmm. So I misunderstood the 250 ms mentioned in your question? Instead, you are really doing ***45 s*** active duration at 75 mA? With only 10 s sleep times and, and I'm confused about this, 30 s of battery disconnect? Could you explain and describe the reason for these three phases? (I can assume that the active phase *does something important*, but why are there two other phases rather than only one other phase? Why not just sleep? Or why not just have the battery disconnected the entire time?)

Comment: event would only be about 250 mS @ ~75mA. The system will remain powered up for about 45 seconds with ~ duty cycle of 10 sec sleep @ 0.5mA if PS mode is enabled - 250mS of event @ 75 mA. Then for about 30 seconds, the battery will be completely disconnected before cycle repeats.

Comment: the hardware that I have designed keep the battery connected as long as user is using the system - ~45 sec (which can be changed but at this stage of my project, I would prefer not to). To keep the power consumption low, I sleep in between the events. Then for about 30 sec, user would stop using the system, that's when battery is completely disconnected..

Comment: Now we are finally starting to get the fuller picture. I'd like to suggest that next time posting a question here that you think about fully disclosing all this right away. Dragging things out, piece-meal like this, is time consuming for you and a waste of everyone else's time and energy, too. At least now I have some idea of the situation, though.

Comment: Yes if you look at the efficiency graphs it drops a lot at small mA

Comment: @jonk, thanks..I will try to include more details to begin with..@Trevor, Yes with this one, efficiency drops significantly with small current but it's better with PS mode enabled. But as I asked earlier, can I keep it enabled all time and would the regulator start at lower voltage with PS enabled? I am also trying to find some better alternatives but in case if I have to use this or similar, please advise on this PS mode for my application..Let me know if I need to clarify this any further..thank you all..

Comment: @user101095 Why are you consuming any power at all in between active periods? In other words, is there anything important going on while sleeping that requires you to have the battery attached at these times? Or would it be just as good if I could suggest a method where the only time there is any power consumed at all is during the active times and that the system can apply some kind of mysterious magic so that when those services are needed it is "magically there" and running for that short 1/4 second?

Comment: @jonk, I see what you are suggesting.. it's just that at this stage, I have the hardware and software designed & tested according to this approach and due to time pressure at this stage of the design, I would have to select the right DC boost regulator and proceed to layout phase...

Comment: Why not using two boost converters instead of one? Use one to power the mcu and another one to power the intermittent load. Optimize each one of the boost converters for the right load

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'll just summarize the commentary. I don't expect this to be an answer, just what I see from the discussion.

I'm imagining something like the following image.

[image]

There are some spikes in the required current, which last \$250\:\text{ms}\$. The required current peaks at around \$75\:\text{mA}\$ and then falls back to some other current level (sleeping) for approximately \$10\:\text{s}\$, though this period is variable. Every \$45\:\text{s}\$, the battery is removed (no clue, at all, as to why -- it's all just magic to me) for about \$30\:\text{s}\$. So the total cycle time is \$75\:\text{s}\$.

The goal is to minimize the average power to help maximize the length of service for a battery system, before replacement.

---

From the above, I would also assume the following:

- No services are being provided while the system is sleeping. So it would be still better if no power was consumed in between. In other words, the only useful periods are the ones that are occasional and consume \$75\:\text{mA}\$ for \$250\:\text{ms}\$.

Because of the length of time for the active period being \$250\:\text{ms}\$, I feel it's just fine to continue the idea of using a PIC MCU. The complaint I might otherwise have, were the period much shorter, would be that it takes a while to get a PIC MCU started from a "cold" sleep -- the oscillator just takes time to get up to speed. On the other hand, an MSP430 can fire up to full speed in about \$1\:\mu\text{s}\$. But given the duration, the MSP430 advantages mostly disappear. So that makes me quite comfortable with the PIC MCU approach here.

As I gather things, you need about \$20\:\text{mC}\$ of charge during the active period of time. The PIC MCU has a range of voltages over which it operates, and similar things can be said about whatever else is attached. Let's say that the allowances you can accept are a droop of no more than \$200\:\text{mV}\$ during the active period. Ignoring contributions by the battery, and putting the entire burden onto a capacitor, this means a capacitor value of \$100\:\text{mF}\$. With a low voltage type, it doesn't have to be that expensive or large. And this assumes that the battery itself can't contribute during this time (which it probably can.)

The average current required is less than \$2\:\text{mA}\$, given your statement of about \$10\:\text{s}\$ between activation events. This can be provided by something as little as a CR2032 lithium battery (which is not known for high currents.) Perhaps placing a capacitor in parallel with such a battery, with a current limiting resistor of course, would provide the necessary power supply without the need, cost, complexity, and/or quiescent losses of a voltage regulator.

Of course, you have other issues to deal with and I have only a very narrow tube-like perspective on your project. But what you've written so far takes me towards that kind of consideration as an alternative path.

The approach I'd like to have you consider would be to arrange things to use a capacitor as your reserve storage, add a current limit arrangement to the circuit so that the CR2032 battery isn't hit hard when first charging the capacitor, and just go with that. The PIC MCU can go into a decent sleep with fairly low draw. End of story.

Comment: thanks jonk, I am planning to use alkaline batteries - like AA / AAA. As per your suggestion, I will consider having a cap like (33 uF ?) across the batteries. But again going back to the original question, can I keep Power save mode enabled all time for my DC regulator like TPS61201? How would the switching frequency vary / affected in PS mode enabled? Would variable switching frequency be a concern in EMC? Thank you..

Comment: @user101095 With Alkaline batteries, there is no need for a capacitor. They can easily provide that level of current. So no cap, no current limit resistor, just instead a direct connection. Their voltages go from about 1.56 V when full to about 1.2 V when "dead." Stacking two means about 3.1 V to about 2.4 V. If you use a PIC that can operate down to some minimum voltage, you can divide that by 2 to get the lifetime for your battery pair. AA batteries have no problem delivering 75 mA even at 1.2 V.

Comment: @user101095 Unless you have another reason for the TPS regulator, I'd eliminate it entirely and exclusively use parts that can operate over the same voltage range as the PIC can. The regulator adds cost, takes space, consumes power when you don't want it to do so, and decreases reliability. There are no good arguments for it, at all, unless there are other parts which require it. The PIC, when it sleeps deep, draws negligible power (1 microamp or less, even with the RTC and watchdog running.) But this is where I'm ignorant. I have no clue what else needs doing here.

Comment: there are other parts of the circuit that require 3.3V regulated..so, again I am going back to the original question which is still not clear to me..thank you..

Comment: @user101095 There is no energy at all in AA batteries after about 1.2 V each (1.1 V is ~0% left.) So you need to work down to 2.3 to 2.4 V, I believe. Not down to 1.6 V. Since you have 3.3 V parts, you are absolutely correct about needing a boost and I'm wrong about the idea of just using batteries directly. I hadn't taken that point until now. Sorry about that. I suppose we are back to something like the TPS61221. I guess I'll delete my answer soon.